# Translating screen touch position to world position in AR with AR Foundation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I'm having a problem with translating the touch position into world coordinates. I want to be able to place an object where I clicked on the plane, but I'm having trouble with Z axis.

I'm translating the Vector2 touch position into world position using `camera.ScreenToWorldPoint()`, but I can't seem to get the Z axis right.

```
Vector3 pos = new Vector3(vector2.x, vector2.y);
pos = camera.ViewportToScreenPoint(pos);
Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, 0));
RaycastHit hit;

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))   
{
    distance = hit.distance;    
}

pos = new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, distance);
return camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need/it makes no sense to convert it first via `ViewportToScreenPoint` .. [`Touch.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-position.html) already is in pixel screen space.

Then you can directly pass it into [`ScreenPointToRay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html) which expects such a pixel space position.

And finally if you already have a `RaycastHit` it makes no sense to again recalculate the 3D world space position via the `hit.distance` but rather simply directly use the [`RaycastHit.point`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-point.html)!

So assuming that `vector2` equals your touch position in **pixel space** it would rather be simply

```
var ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(vector2);

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit))   
{
    var hitPos = hit.point;

    // ... whatever you want to do with the hit position   
}
```

open question is: What shall be returned if nothing is hit by the ray?